# Does FtpWebRequest TLS connection need a client certificate?

Tags: c#, ftp, client-certificates, ftpwebrequest, ftps

I'm trying to create a `FTPRequest` using `FtpWebRequest` to send a report file to my server. But i don't understand about SSL/TLS connection.

The server I'm using accepts TLS connections. So, is just setting `EnableSsl = true` enough? Or do I need a client certificate?

If I just set to `EnableSsl` to `true` the connection is accepted and the file sent.

```
ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
ftpRequest.Proxy = null;
ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

If I want TLS/SSL:

```
ftpRequest.EnableSsl = true;
X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(filePath);

X509CertificateCollection certCollection = new X509CertificateCollection { cert };

ftpRequest.ClientCertificates = certCollection;
```

If I set the certificate and try to connect, the server does not respond and don't give me any exception.
Do I really need a certificate? I don't know if the certificate is having a difference on connection or not. What's the purpose of certificate?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A client certificate is a way of an authentication (as an alternative or a complement to a password). You need it only, if your FTPS server requires an authentication with a client certificate. It's similar to authentication with a private key in SSH.

In my experience, client certificates are used very rarely. Had you needed it, you would know. And you would typically not have a password (though it's possible, while even rarer, that your need both a password and a client certificate to authenticate).

So usually, to use FTPS (FTP over TLS/SSL), all you need is:

```
ftpRequest.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: I appreciate  your help. Thanks!!